find duplicates values in a list of dictionaries while a key's value have some similarities
With this question and its answers, I know how can I find if a key has duplicate values, but my issue is this:
This is my list:
list1 = [
    {'name': 'saeed1-gr1', 'id': 1},
    {'name': 'pl1-saeed1', 'id': 1},
    {'name': 'saeed11-gr2', 'id': 8},
    {'name': 'pl1-saeed2', 'id': 2},
    {'name': 'saeed3-gr2', 'id': 8},
    {'name': 'saeed5-gr1', 'id': 3},
    {'name': 'pl1-saeed7', 'id': 1},
    {'name': 'saeed15-gr1', 'id': 1},
    {'name': 'ps1-saeed15', 'id': 1},
    {'name': 'ps1-saeed11', 'id': 1},
    {'name': 'saeed8-gr3', 'id': 1},
]

I'm going to find this:
for name in list1: if there is gr1 in name['name'] and id is the same, then print names A and B have same id.
for name in list1: if there is gr2 in name['name'] and id is the same, then print names A and B have same id.
for name in list1: if there is gr3 in name['name'] and id is the same, then print names A and B have same id.
for name in list1: if there is pl1 in name['name'] and id is the same, then print names A and B have same id.
for name in list1: if there is ps1 in name['name'] and id is the same, then print names A and B have same id.

I intentionally added only one gr3 in order to have one of it only.
I was trying something like this but it failed:
tmp = []
for name1 in list1:
    for name2 in list1:
        if name1['name'] != name2['name'] and name1['id'] == name2['id'] and name1['name'] not in tmp:
            tmp.append(name1['name'])
            print(f'equal {name1["name"]} == {name2["name"]} with same id {name1["id"]}')

But this what I have with my attempt:
equal saeed1-gr1 == pl1-saeed1 with same id 1
equal pl1-saeed1 == saeed1-gr1 with same id 1
equal saeed11-gr2 == saeed1-gr1 with same id 1
equal saeed3-gr2 == saeed1-gr1 with same id 1
equal pl1-saeed7 == saeed1-gr1 with same id 1
equal saeed15-gr1 == saeed1-gr1 with same id 1
equal ps1-saeed15 == saeed1-gr1 with same id 1
equal ps1-saeed11 == saeed1-gr1 with same id 1
equal saeed8-gr3 == saeed1-gr1 with same id 1

Expected output is like this:
names saeed1-gr1 and saeed15-gr1 same id 1
names saeed11-gr2 and saeed3-gr2 same id 8
names pl1-saeed1 and pl1-saeed7 same id 1
names ps1-saeed15 and ps1-saeed11 same id 1


I think you were after something like this:
list1 = [
    {'name': 'saeed1-gr1', 'id': 1},
    {'name': 'pl1-saeed1', 'id': 1},
    {'name': 'saeed11-gr2', 'id': 8},
    {'name': 'pl1-saeed2', 'id': 2},
    {'name': 'saeed3-gr2', 'id': 8},
    {'name': 'saeed5-gr1', 'id': 3},
    {'name': 'pl1-saeed7', 'id': 1},
    {'name': 'saeed15-gr1', 'id': 1},
    {'name': 'ps1-saeed15', 'id': 1},
    {'name': 'ps1-saeed11', 'id': 1},
    {'name': 'saeed8-gr3', 'id': 1},
]

parts = ['pl1', 'ps1', 'gr1', 'gr2', 'gr3']

result = {}
for item in list1:
    # would you have names with multiple parts?
    for part in parts:
        if part in item['name']:
            # dictionary of (id, part) -> [names]
            result[key] = result.get(key := (item['id'], part), []) + [item['name']]

# using id_ to avoid shadowing built-in id() function
for (id_, part), values in result.items():
    print(f'for id {id_} and part {part}: {values}')

But if you only want to print the duplicates of course:
for (id_, part), values in result.items():
    if len(values) > 1:
        print(f'for id {id_} and part {part}: {values}')

Output:
for id 1 and part gr1: ['saeed1-gr1', 'saeed15-gr1']
for id 1 and part pl1: ['pl1-saeed1', 'pl1-saeed7']
for id 8 and part gr2: ['saeed11-gr2', 'saeed3-gr2']
for id 1 and part ps1: ['ps1-saeed15', 'ps1-saeed11']


You could build a dictionary that consolidates the information that you have in your original list of dictionaries.
Something like this:
from collections import defaultdict

list1 = [
    {"name": "saeed1-gr1", "id": 1},
    {"name": "pl1-saeed1", "id": 1},
    {"name": "saeed11-gr2", "id": 8},
    {"name": "pl1-saeed2", "id": 2},
    {"name": "saeed3-gr2", "id": 8},
    {"name": "saeed5-gr1", "id": 3},
    {"name": "pl1-saeed7", "id": 1},
    {"name": "saeed15-gr1", "id": 1},
    {"name": "ps1-saeed15", "id": 1},
    {"name": "ps1-saeed11", "id": 1},
    {"name": "saeed8-gr3", "id": 1},
]

parts = {"gr1", "pl1", "gr2", "gr3", "ps1"}

rd = defaultdict(dict)

for d in list1:
    try:
        a, b = d["name"].split("-")
        if a in parts:
            rd[a].setdefault(d["id"], []).append(d)
        elif b in parts:
            rd[b].setdefault(d["id"], []).append(d)
    except ValueError:
        pass

for v in rd.values():
    for _id, _v in v.items():
        if len(_v) > 1:
            names = [_d["name"] for _d in _v]
            print("names", " and ".join(names), "same id", _id)

Output:
names saeed1-gr1 and saeed15-gr1 same id 1
names pl1-saeed1 and pl1-saeed7 same id 1
names saeed11-gr2 and saeed3-gr2 same id 8
names ps1-saeed15 and ps1-saeed11 same id 1


I added comments to each part, and I also added another case where more than 2 items are similar.
from itertools import *

arr = [
    {'name': 'saeed1-gr1', 'id': 1},
    {'name': 'pl1-saeed1', 'id': 1},
    {'name': 'saeed11-gr2', 'id': 8},
    {'name': 'pl1-saeed2', 'id': 2},
    {'name': 'saeed3-gr2', 'id': 8},
    {'name': 'saeed5-gr1', 'id': 3},
    {'name': 'pl1-saeed7', 'id': 1},
    {'name': 'saeed15-gr1', 'id': 1},
    {'name': 'ps1-saeed15', 'id': 1},
    {'name': 'ps1-saeed11', 'id': 1},
    {'name': 'saeed11-ps1', 'id': 1},
    {'name': 'saeed8-gr3', 'id': 1},
]

# split name and sort by length of the parts, dropping the longest (saeedX in this case)
step1 = [(v['id'], *sorted(v['name'].split('-'),key=len)[:-1],v) for v in arr]
# sort by id then short part of name
step2 = sorted(step1, key=lambda x: (x[0],x[1]))
# group by id then short part of name
for k,g in groupby(step2, lambda x:(x[0],x[1])):
    items = list(g)
    if len(items) > 1:
        # print values, I added another line at the end of the input, so it can display more than just 2 of the same values
        print(f'names '+', '.join([f"{i[-1]['name']}" for i in items[:-1]])+f" and {items[-1][-1]['name']} same id {k[0]}")


Instead of hardcoding all the keys such as 'gr1', 'pl1', 'gr2', etc., you can filter out tokens that contain 'saeed' instead:
from operator import itemgetter

dupes = {}
for name, id in map(itemgetter('name', 'id'), list1):
    dupes.setdefault(
        (next(token for token in name.split('-') if 'saeed' not in token), id), []
    ).append(name)
for (_, id), names in dupes.items():
    if len(names) > 1:
        print(f'names {" and ".join(names)} same id {id}')

This outputs:
names saeed1-gr1 and saeed15-gr1 same id 1
names pl1-saeed1 and pl1-saeed7 same id 1
names saeed11-gr2 and saeed3-gr2 same id 8
names ps1-saeed15 and ps1-saeed11 same id 1

Demo: https://ideone.com/XksMjN

Thanks, but the real-world example doesn't contain the same word between all of them. They have one thing like gr1 actually.
